# SQL Server : setting date using DATEPART

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with some rows that have had their date year set to 1990. I want to set all these rows to 2016. So for example, 1990-01-06 will become 2016-01-06.

This is what I have up to now

```
UPDATE [tableName]
SET recievedDate = new DateTime() 
     //where I want to make a new datetime with 2016 as the year
WHERE DATEPART(yyyy, receivedDate) = '1990' 
  AND DATEPART(mm, receivedDate) = '01';
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `DATEADD` to add `26` years to `1990`:

```
CREATE TABLE #tableName(receivedDate DATE);
INSERT INTO #tableName(receivedDate) VALUES ('1990-01-06'),('1990-01-16');

UPDATE #tableName
SET receivedDate = DATEADD(YEAR, 26, receivedDate)
WHERE DATEPART(yyyy, receivedDate) = '1990' 
  AND DATEPART(mm, receivedDate) = '01';

SELECT *
FROM #tableName;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/425751)**</kbd>

---

**SQL Server 2012+** you could use [`DATEFROMPARTS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213228.aspx):

```
UPDATE #tableName
SET receivedDate = DATEFROMPARTS(2016,
                                 DATEPART(mm, receivedDate),
                                 DATEPART(dd, receivedDate)
                                )
WHERE DATEPART(yyyy, receivedDate) = '1990' 
  AND DATEPART(mm, receivedDate) = '01';
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo2`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/425754)**</kbd>

**EDIT**

Keep in that expression  `DATEPART(yyyy, receivedDate) = '1990'` is not [SARGable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799584/what-makes-a-sql-statement-sargable) and query optimizer will skip index ob `receivedDate`(if exists any). You could use `BETWEEN` or `>= <` like [Gordon Linoff](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34899212/5070879) proposed.

Answer (score 1):

Since `CONVERT(varchar, yourdate, 126)` returns a string in folwoing format "2016-01-04T07:45:00" one can just use following statement:

```
update YourTable set 
    yourdate = CAST('2016' + substring(CONVERT(varchar, yourdate, 126), 5, 15) as datetime)
where YEAR(yourdate) = 1990 AND MONTH(yordate) = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

The right solution is to add 26 years as lad2025 explains.  However, the query itself is better written like this:

```
UPDATE tableName
    SET receivedDate = DATEADD(YEAR, 26, receivedDate)
    WHERE receivedDate >= '1990-01-01' AND
          receivedDate < '1990-02-01';
```

This version allows the query to take advantage of any index that includes `receivedDate` as the first column, which can be a significant improvement in performance.

Comment:  For SARGable query :)